# Intellij IDEA Java code formatting: can I force a newline after public and before a method return type?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I would like my java method declarations to look like:

```
static public
boolean method1(int arg1) {
...
}
```

where there is a newline after `public` and before `boolean`.  Is there a way to do that in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Looks strange why you want it this way?

Comment: On long method declaration lines, I like to see the return type on the left.  Just personal preference, like a lot of code-style questions.  Not sure why you would vote this question down just because you disagree with the style choice.

Comment: @Doug How do you know who voted your question down?

Comment: I don't know for 100% certain, but his comment and the down vote happened at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relevant post.
*[Software Engineering Stack Exchange – Reason for placing function type and method name on different lines in C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200828/reason-for-placing-function-type-and-method-name-on-different-lines-in-c)*.

You can find this in *Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java*.
The title is, *"Modifer list"*, and the option is *"Wrap after modifier list"*.